# Expected area of a triangle inscribed in a square containing the centroid

Tags: probability, statistics, euclidean-geometry

This question is similar to a few others that have been asked but with a slight modification.

Question: Choose three random points, $A, B$ and $C$ on a unit square. Consider the triangle that is formed from those three points. What is the expected area of the triangle inscribed in the unit square such that the triangle contains the square's centroid?

Comment: Are you going to show an attempt?

Comment: If I fixed two points and made the third point random, I could find the probability that the triangle formed by the three points contains the square's centroid

Comment: One alternative perspective is to consider three lines such that their pairwise intersections are the points, the area can be obtained via the inclusion exclusion principle and it is more obvious when the center of the square is in the triangle or not.

Comment: After breaking it down to cases: fix A to one edge, 16 cases for B and C on various edges, I would try to integrate the shoelace formula over the range of coordinates satisfying the centroid condition for each point, but I have a feeling it's the long way around.